# Count of each characters in given string

Tags: oracle, plsql

**I require the count of each character in a string.**
Example:

```
SELECT ('aabcccdee') from dual;
```

Result:

```
a(1),b(2), c(3), d(1),e(2).
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its generally considered good to show what you have tried or researched.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hierarchical query to split your string into it individual characters; this is using a CTE just to supply your example value:

```
with t (value) as (
  select 'aabcccdee' from dual
)
select substr(value, level, 1) as a_char
from t
connect by level <= length(value);
```

Then you can use aggregation to count how may times each appears:

```
with t (value) as (
  select 'aabcccdee' from dual
)
select a_char, count(*) a_count
from (
  select substr(value, level, 1) as a_char
  from t
  connect by level <= length(value)
)
group by a_char
order by a_char;

A_CH    A_COUNT
---- ----------
a             2
b             1
c             3
d             1
e             2
```

And you can use `listagg()` (if you're on 11g or above) to aggregate those characters and counts into a single string if that's what you really want:

```
with t (value) as (
  select 'aabcccdee' from dual
)
select listagg(a_char || '(' || count(*) || ')', ',') within group (order by a_char)
from (
  select substr(value, level, 1) as a_char
  from t
  connect by level <= length(value)
)
group by a_char;

LISTAGG(A_CHAR||'('||COUNT(*)||')',',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYA_CHAR)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
a(2),b(1),c(3),d(1),e(2)
```

If you particularly want to do this in PL/SQL - because you value is already in a PL/SQL variable perhaps - you can do the same thing with a context switch:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_value varchar2(30) := 'aabcccdee';
  l_result varchar2(100);
begin
  select listagg(a_char || '(' || count(*) || ')', ',') within group (order by a_char)
  into l_result
  from (
    select substr(l_value, level, 1) as a_char
    from dual
    connect by level <= length(l_value)
  )
  group by a_char;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
end;
/

a(2),b(1),c(3),d(1),e(2)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Its good to see the way the query builds as extra requirements are considered.

Comment: This is awesome Alex. You gave no scope for anyone to answer any other way. +1